# onClick function activated when clicking out of the button in a React application

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am making a react application with two buttons and onClick functions. The bottom "-" button is leaking also on parts of the "+" button. I made an image for clarity, where it shows the activated button on each area:

[image: Demo]

The onClick function is assigned to each button and there are no child elements.

I already looked at margin, padding, border, and line height without success.

Right now the only solution I found (which doesn't solve the entire problem) is to add margin on top of the minus button and make sure plus works all over the plus area. However, this adds white-space between the buttons and it doesn't look exactly like it should.

The code:

```
import "./MenuItem.scss";

export default function MenuItem(props) {
    return <>
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-12 col-md-4 picture">
                    {props.item.likes ? <div className="heartContainer"><div>{props.item.likes}</div></div> : null}
                    <img className="w-100" src={`${props.item.img}`} alt={props.item.title} />
                </div>
                <div className="col-12 col-md-6 description">
                    <h4>{props.item.title}</h4>
                    <p>{props.item.subtitle ? props.item.subtitle + ' / ' : null} € {props.item.price}</p>
                    <p className="desc">{props.item.description}</p>
                </div>
                <div className="col-12 col-md-2 buttons mx-0 my-2">
                    <button className="btn minus-mobile" onClick={(e) => props.removeFromCart(props.item)}>&ndash;</button>
                    <div className="m-0">
                        <button className="btn plus" onClick={(e) => props.addToCart(props.item)}>+</button>
                        <button className="btn minus" onClick={(e) => props.removeFromCart(props.item)}>&ndash;</button>
                    </div>
                    <div className="counter m-0">{props.cart[props.item.title] ? props.cart[props.item.title].quantity : 0}</div>
                    <button className="btn plus-mobile" onClick={(e) => props.addToCart(props.item)}>+</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </>
}
```

Props:

```
const addToCart = (item) => {
        if (cart[item.title]) {
            // another item added
            item.quantity = cart[item.title].quantity + 1;
        } else {
            // first item added
            item.quantity = 1;
        }
        let newCart = { ...cart, [item.title]: item };
        setCart(newCart);
    };

    const removeFromCart = (item) => {
        let newCart = {};
        if (cart[item.title]) {
            if (cart[item.title].quantity > 1) {
                // more than one item
                item.quantity = cart[item.title].quantity - 1;
                newCart = { ...cart, [item.title]: item };
            } else if (cart[item.title].quantity === 1) {
                delete cart[item.title];
                newCart = cart;
                setZero(!zero);
            }
        } else {
            // no items left
            return;
        }
        setCart(newCart);
    };
```

Comment: only i cant open image, please put your code here

Comment: Why not both? keep the image but add the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:

Added this style to the element:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Answer (score 0):

It may happen because of button styles. Try `display: block` for buttons and add `display: flex; flex-direction: column` for its parent element.

Comment: This is already applied `display: flex; flex-direction: column`, I tried to switch the buttons to `display: block` but without success.